# Applying dependent mathematical operation to column in multi-indexed dataframe based on far left index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to add a column of data that is calculated from an existing column, based on the far left index of a multi-indexed dataframe.

For this instance, I have a column of stats, and my far left index is the player, and the next level index is the season. I'd like to add a column that is a relative stats number, based on percentage of each players max stat.

So for the below data frame, I'd like to add a column that is rStats (relative Stats), where the first entry would be =5/7, the second would be =6/7, the third would be =7/7, and then once it gets to a new player, it would use their max, so entry 4 would be =3/5, and so on.

```
                    Stats
Stephen Curry 2010      5
              2011      6
              2012      7
Chris Paul    2010      3
              2011      4
              2012      5
```

I've created a series of the max stats (df.groupby('Player')['Stats'].max()), and try to create a for loop that applies the correct mathematical operation based on the entry in the df, but can't get it to work correctly.

Here's the code to replicate a simplified version of the dataframe, as shown above:

```
import pandas as pd

players = ['Stephen Curry','Stephen Curry','Stephen Curry','Chris Paul','Chris Paul','Chris Paul']
years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012]
stats = [5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=[players,years],columns=['Stats'],data=stats)
```

Comment: This would be improved if you showed exactly what you tried and the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A faster approach than `groupby.apply` would be to combine `GroupBy.max` and `.div` matching indexes on `level=0`

```
df.div(df.groupby(level=0).max(), level=0)
```

or you can do this only on the series itself

```
df.Stats.div(df.Stats.groupby(level=0).max(), level=0)
```

---

```
                       Stats
Stephen Curry 2010  0.714286
              2011  0.857143
              2012  1.000000
Chris Paul    2010  0.600000
              2011  0.800000
              2012  1.000000
```

---

`Timings`

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000)

%timeit df.div(df.groupby(level=0).max(), level=0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.02 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x/x.max())
1 loop, best of 3: 8.88 s per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [groupby.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df['rstats']=df.groupby(level=0)['Stats'].apply(lambda x: x/x.max())
```

**Or better 
what @Quang Hoang suggested:**

```
df['rstats']=df['Stats']/df.groupby(level=0)['Stats'].transform('max')
```

---

```
                    Stats    rstats
Stephen Curry 2010      5  0.714286
              2011      6  0.857143
              2012      7  1.000000
Chris Paul    2010      3  0.600000
              2011      4  0.800000
              2012      5  1.000000
```

Comment: `transform('max')` and divide would be faster: `df['Stats']/df.groupby(level=0).Stats.transform('max')`

Comment: Thanks! But I realized this doesn't work for my full df with multiple columns... If I needed to specify the 'Stats' column because others are strings, how would I need to edit this implementation?

Comment: i am glad to help!